# \newline in \vbox in heading

Tags: boxes

I have this heading

```
\def\@oddhead{\vbox{\vss\centerline{\color{gray}\small { \bf \texttt{Article 
published in \textit{\thejournalname}. doi: 10.1029/2019False1234  \newline \textcopyright 2020 American Foo Bar. All Rights Reserved} } }\vskip24pt } }
\let\@evenhead\@oddhead
}
```

The problem is that the `\newline` is not working, and thus the heading appears in a single line.

Is there any way to force a new line in a `\vbox`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? And why are you using a `\vbox` and not something like `\parbox` (which does support `\newline)

Comment: @daleif If I use \parbox the header does not show up

Comment: Then show a complete (but minimal) example. I use parbox in headers all the time without issues.

Comment: `\def`, `\vbox`, `\vss`,  `\let`  are tex primitives `\centerline` is a plain tex macro in latex but not fitting the latex box system so shouldn't be used, `\bf` is not defined by default in latex. Given that so little of the code you post is actually latex it's not surprising that `\newline` does not work (but `\centerline` is like `\mbox` and is always one line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make a line break in `\centerline`, which is not allowed.

You might do

```latex
\makeatletter
\def\@oddhead{%
  \vbox to \headheight{
    \vss
    \color{gray}\small\bfseries\ttfamily
    \centerline{Article published in \textit{\thejournalname}. doi: 10.1029/2019False1234}
    \centerline{\textcopyright 2020 American Foo Bar. All Rights Reserved}
  }%
}
\let\@evenhead\@oddhead
\makeatother
```

but using a `\parbox` is easier.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}

\pagestyle{headings}

\makeatletter
\def\@oddhead{%
  \parbox[b][\headheight]{\textwidth}{
    \centering\color{gray}\small\bfseries\ttfamily
    Article published in \textit{\thejournalname}. doi: 10.1029/2019False1234\\
    \textcopyright 2020 American Foo Bar. All Rights Reserved
  }%
}
\let\@evenhead\@oddhead
\makeatother

\providecommand{\thejournalname}{Foo Journal}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note.** The standard fonts don't have boldface typewriter type. Since the font used by the OP is unknown, I left the `\bfseries` declaration.